# How to model inheritance relationship in Functional Programming

Tags: oop, inheritance, f#, functional-programming

Object Oriented programming paradigm uses inheritance to model relationships between entities that follow Generalization-Specialization relationship. Here, a Base class is used to encapsulate the common (General) attributes and behavior of a set of entities and the Derived Classes *extend* the base class by adding additional attributes and/or adding/modifying existing behavior.

As someone new to Functional Programming, I need guidance on modeling such relationships in functional languages like F#.

e.g. what would be the best approach to model a simple situation like the following:

```
abstract class Tutorial { 
  private String topic;
  abstract public void learn();
}

class VideoTutorial extends Tutorial {
  private float duration;
  public void learn () {
    System.out.println ("Watch Video");
  }
}

class PDFTutorial extends Tutorial {
  private int pageCount;
  public void learn () {
    System.out.println ("Read PDF");
  }
}
```

and then later use a collection of *Tutorials* and call *learn*  to observe polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the functional design, you think about things a bit differently, so the ideas will not map perfectly. Typically, functional design focuses more on data types that express the entities you are working with. In your case, you could define `TutorialKind` which is either video or PDF using a discriminated union and `Tutorial` would then be a record that consits of a kind and its topic:

```
type TutorialKind = 
  | VideoTutorial of duration:float
  | PDFTutorial of pageCount:int

type Tutorial = 
  { Kind : TutorialKind
    Topic : string }
```

Note that this keeps just the data about tutorials. Any functionality can be implemented in functions that pattern match on the kind of the tutorial:

```
let learn tutorial = 
  match tutorial.Kind with
  | VideoTutorial _ -> printfn "Watch video"
  | PDFTutorial _ -> printfn "Read PDF"
```

Note that this is extensible in a different direction than the OO version. In OO, you can easily add new subclasses; here you can easily add new functions. In practice, functional people are usually happy with this change, but F# is a mixed language and if you need "OO-style extensibility", you can easily use interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the change in thought process. But with this approach, doesn't it mean that in  case, I later wish to add AudioTutorial, I'll need to modify the two types as well as the learn function. Please guide me, is OO approach better suited for such situations.

Comment: @S.Singh - Yes, it means that if you want to add `AudioTutorial`, you will need to modify the `TutorialKind` type and the `learn` function. However, if you wanted to add a function that does something else with the tutorials, you will only need to write a function (rather than modifying all the classes, which you would have to do in OO). So, the change in perspective works both ways... In F#, the functional style is a good default, but you can use OO and interfaces if you are building something with plugins where you really need the OO kind of extensibility.

Comment: Yes, to add new types of tutorials, you do need to modify the type and all functions that work with it. In C#, on the other hand, to add new _operations_ you do need to modify every single existing type. It is generally considered kinda hard for a programming language to have it both ways. This problem is such a common place, it has its own name - the [Expression Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). C# solves only one half of the problem, and F# solves both, but not at the same time.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - Can you please explain "F# solves both, but not at the same time". Does it refer to the hybrid nature of the language, where we can model our data either the Functional way or the OO way...

Comment: Yes. In F# you can either model your domain with classes and interfaces or you can model with discriminated unions. The former gives you easy way to add new types, the latter - easy way to add new operations. But you can't do both at the same time.

Comment: One advantage to F#'s approach, where if you define a new type you have to add it to all the functions, is that the compiler will *help you do this*. If you add an AudioTutorial type, you'll get lots of compiler warnings saying "This match expression is incomplete: AudioTutorial is not handled". Fix all those warnings, and you've made your code work again. This is not something that C# can do for you: when you add a new operation, C# can't tell you all the places where you need to change your code to make it work. So I prefer F#'s approach because the compiler helps me write my code!

Comment: @rmunn actually, if you add a new abstract method to the base class (or interface), the compiler _does_ tell you to fix all classes that inherit from (or implement) it.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - You're right. I'd edit my comment to remove the incorrect statement but it's been more than five minutes so it's too late to edit. But for the record, C# also allows the compiler to help you write your code in this scenario.